# Return car make by providing car model from XML file using .asmx web service

Tags: asp.net, xml, vb.net

I am writing an .asmx web service to return all car makes matching a requested model from within an XML file.

Using VB in ASP.net, can you suggest how I could:

1) first find a match to the requested make, then
2) return all models?

Below is a sample of the XML.  Thanks!

```
<cars>
  <car>
    <carmake>Acura</carmake>
    <carmodels>
      <carmodel>ILX</carmodel>
      <carmodel>MDX</carmodel>
      <carmodel>RDX</carmodel>
    </carmodels>
  </car>

  <car>
    <carmake>Aston Martin</carmake>
    <carmodels>
      <carmodel>DB9</carmodel>
      <carmodel>DBS</carmodel>
      <carmodel>Rapide</carmodel>
    </carmodels>
  </car>
</cars>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that by using XPath

```
Dim doc As New Xml.XmlDocument
doc.LoadXml("yourinputxmlasstring")

Dim maker As String = "Aston Martin"
For Each x As Xml.XmlNode In doc.SelectNodes("cars/car[carmake='" + maker + "']")
    For Each p As Xml.XmlNode In x.SelectNodes("carmodels/carmodel")
        Console.WriteLine(p.InnerText)
    Next
Next
```

Comment: Thanks. Tried this, got an error on the doc.LoadXml line: 
Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1.

Comment: Problem solved: I used doc.Load instead of doc.LoadXml.  Thanks - this code works perfectly!

Comment: Any suggestions on how to convert the search to look for lower case?  maker.tolower works, but what about the "cars/car[carmake=" string?

Comment: xpath is case sensitive; if you need case insensitivity in you search than you need to change code above and use doc.SelectNodes("cars/car"), then get carmake node value and compare using case insensitive comparison